# ROR + Google Book API - Unable to store book data using ISBN number

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-books

In my sample project, I am trying to access Google Book API using URL but I am not able to store book details in database using isbn number.

```
url = URI.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?isbn=xxxxxxxxxx')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.
```

I am not able to figure out  that where I am lacking, may be approach is wrong.

In my controller I tried above sample code to access the values but no success. Is there any other way to handle this.

Error occured while using googlebook gem
[image]

Comment: What is the latest on this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Anything on this yet?

Comment: NO Progress .. Infact I found one issue with google api that api is not rendering right result due to change in current api format.

Comment: Then you should update your post with this useful information.